# Retrofit2: Trying to Post Object which has multiple objects in it as Json?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have Content class like that;

public class Content {

```
@SerializedName("id")
long id;
@SerializedName("content_type")
ContentType contentType;

long content_type_id;

@SerializedName("created_date")
Date createdDate;

@SerializedName("modified_date")
Date modifiedDate;

@SerializedName("components")
List<Component> components;

User owner;
```

These User, Component and ContentType are classes that I have created. I want to convert this class into Json like that;

```
{
    "content_type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Post",
        "components": [
            "text",
            "longtext",
            "video"
        ],
        "component_names": [
            "title",
            "body",
            "video"
        ]
    },
    "owner": {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1/",
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@admin.com"
    },
    "owner_id": 1,
    "content_type_id": 1,
    "components": [
        {
            "component_type": "text",
            "order": 1,
            "type_data": {
                "data": "Amber Run - Found"
            }
        },
        {
            "component_type": "longtext",
            "order": 2,
            "type_data": {
                "data": "Warning sign"
            }
        },
        {
            "component_type": "video",
            "order": 3,
            "type_data": {
                "data": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj6V_a1-EUA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I send this raw Json data with PostMan, it works.

I am using this method in RetrofitApiService interface

```
 @POST("group-contents/{group_id}/")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Content> postContent(@Path(value = "group_id", encoded = true)  long groupId, @Body Content content);
```

However, I am getting this error

> @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

How should I properly use retrofit to send Json objects like that?

Comment: you should remove @FormUrlEncoded of your interface

Comment: You are doing everything right except annotating the interface call method as `@FormUrlEncoded` which changes the MIME type from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is definitely not what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send that as `RequestBody`, and also have to remove that `@FormUrlEncoded`

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(content) //Here content is your POJO class, that to be send.

RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);

@POST("group-contents/{group_id}/")
Call<Content> postContent(@Path(value = "group_id", encoded = true)  long groupId, @Body RequestBody body);
```

Comment: what do you mean by jsonObject? It did not worked. Btw my content class not extend anything, is it supposed to be extend some Json class?

Comment: No.. That isn't needed. You can use GSON to convert that class to Json, like my answer. I have edited it now.